# How can i change a couple of MovieClip instance properties in mainTimeline by ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm a beginner at ActionScript 3. I want to change a MovieClip property. Also I want to give different names for every instance. So basically I want to reach all instances by one name.

A possible solution is writing code inside the MovieClip timeline with --this--.

But I want to do that in root area.

This a picture of my scene:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzXd1GMzUo9HUWozdkJjYkxXSEk/view?usp=sharing

```
trace(ins1.alpha); // reaching with instance name without problem
trace(ins2.alpha); // reaching with other instance name without problem
/*
trace(MovieClip("mnsmb").alpha);        // trying to reach with linkage name is not working
trace(MovieClip(mnsmb).alpha);          // trying to reach with linkage name is not working
trace(MovieClip("menusembolu").alpha);  // trying to reach with library symbol name is not working
trace(MovieClip(menusembolu).alpha);    // trying to reach with library symbol name is not working
trace(mnsmb.alpha);                     // trying to reach with linkage name is not working
trace(menusembolu.alpha);               // trying to reach with library symbol name is not working
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify the alpha property of one instance (named *inst1* in the Properties panel):

```
ins1.alpha = 0.1;
```

If you want modify the alpha of all the `instances` of your `class`, you can use the `is` operator (*mnsmb* is your AS Linkage):

```
var inst:DisplayObject;

for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
{
    inst = this.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObject;
    if (inst is mnsmb) inst.alpha = 0.1;
}
```

Note : In ActionScript 3.0 the `instanceof` operator should not be used to test for data type membership. See Adobe help about [the is operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8a.html).